# Unwrapping a list or map as function arguments in Scala

Tags: python, scala

Is it possible to dynamically unwrap a list/tuple/map items as arguments to a function in Scala? I am looking for a Scala equivalent of Python's `args`/`kwargs`.

For instance, in Python if a function is defined as `def foo(bar1, bar2, bar3=None, bar4=1)` then given a list `x=[1,7]` and a dictionary `y={'bar3':True, 'bar4':9}` you can call `foo` as `foo(*x, **y)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just to be clear, the following is valid Python code:

```
def foo(bar1, bar2, bar3=None, bar4=1): print("bar1="+str(bar1)+" bar2="+str(bar2)+" bar3="+str(bar3)+" bar4="+str(bar4))
x=[1,7]
y={'bar3':True, 'bar4':9}
foo(*x,**y)
```

However, there is no analogous Scala syntax.  There are some similar things, but the main reason this is never going to be possible is that it would violate the compile-time type checking that Scala requires.  Let's look more closely.

### The reasons

First, think about the varargs portion.  Here you want to be able to pass in an arbitrary-length list of arguments and have it fill in the relevant function parameters.  This will never work in Scala because the type checker requires that the parameters passed into a function be valid.  In your scenario, `foo()` can accept a parameter list `x` of length two, but no less.  But since any `Seq` can have an arbitrary number of parameters, how would the type checker know that the `x` being pass it is valid at compile time?

Second, think about the keywword arguments.  Here you are asking for the function to accept an arbitrary `Map` of arguments and values.  But you get the same problem: How can the compile-time type checker know that you are passing in all of the necessary arguments?  Or, further, that they are the right types?  After all, they example you give is a Map containing both a Boolean and an Int, which would have the type `Map[String, Any]`, so how would the type checker know that this would match your parameter types?

### Some solutions

#### Scala's varargs

You can do some similar things, but not this exactly.  For example, if you defined your function to explicitly use varargs, you can pass in a Seq:

```
def foo(bar1: Int*) = println(f"bar1=$bar1")
val x = Seq(1, 2)
foo(x:_*)
```

This works because Scala knows that it only needs a sequence of zero or more arguments, and a Seq will always contain zero or more items, so it matches.  Further, it only works if the types match as well; here it's expecting a sequence of Ints, and gets it.

#### `tupled`

The other thing you can do is to pass in a **tuple** of arguments:

```
def foo(bar1: Int, bar2: Int, bar3: Boolean = false, bar4: Int = 1) = println(f"bar1=$bar1 bar2=$bar2 bar3=$bar3 bar4=$bar4")
val x = (1, 2, true, 9)
(foo _).tupled(x)
```

Again, this works because Scala's type checker can verify that the arguments are valid.  The function requires four arguments, of types Int, Int, Boolean, and Int, and since a tuple in Scala has a fixed length and known (and possibly different) types for each position, the type-checker can verify that the arguments match the expected parameters.

Comment: You could replace `(foo(_,_,_,_)).tupled` with `(foo _).tupled`.

Comment: @senia, Thanks! I knew there was a way to do that.  I thought I tried it but got an error.  I must have done something else wrong...

Answer (score 3):

Sort of an edge case for the OQ but if you want to pass a Map of arguments for a case class this seems to work:

```
scala> case class myCC(foo: String = "bar", negInt: Int = -1)

scala> val row = myCC()
scala> println(row)
myCC(bar,-1)

scala> val overrides = Map("foo" -> "baz")
scala> row.getClass.getDeclaredFields foreach { f =>
 f.setAccessible(true)
 overrides.foreach{case (k,v) => if (k == f.getName) f.set(row, v)}
}
scala> println(row)
myCC(baz,-1)
```

(borrowed from [Scala: How to access a class property dynamically by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458881/scala-how-to-access-a-class-property-dynamically-by-name))

Answer (score 2):

Original answers don't mention handling Map as list of pairs - it can be easily converted to map (even -> operator is just shorthand for pair).

```
def parse(options: (String, String)*) = println (options.toMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use varargs syntax:

```
def printAll(strings: String*) {
  strings.map(println)
}
```

No you can use this function so:

```
printAll("foo")
```

so:

```
printAll("foo", "bar")
```

or so:

```
printAll("foo", "bar", "baz")
```