# Can i fill function named parameters from seq in scala?

Tags: function, scala, parameter-passing, sequence

If I have `Seq('a -> 1, 'b -> "some text")`, how can I call a function `f(a: Int, b: String)`, filled with parameters from `Seq`, bound by name (a, b)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731069/unwrapping-a-list-or-map-as-function-arguments-in-scala

Comment: Seq may be Seq('a -> 1, 'b -> "some text"), or Seq('b -> "some text", 'a -> 1), so varargs and tupled are not approach. From post (how i understand): "However, there is no analogous Scala syntax."

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using [scala-reflect](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html), I believe. Something like this (untested):

```
def applyWithNamedParameters[T: ClassTag](obj: T, m: MethodSymbol, params: Map[String, Any]) {
  val methodMirror = scala.universe.runtime.currentMirror.reflect(obj).reflectMethod(m)
  val paramNames = m.paramss.flatten.map(_.name.toString)
  val paramValues = paramNames.map(params)

  methodMirror.apply(paramValues)
}
```

`params` are given as a map instead of Seq to simplify code a bit.